# Opencl kernel runs on Intel platform but not on Nvidia

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I am implementing a ray tracer using openCL. I have installed NVidia's CUDA sdk and everything seems to be set up fine, both my platforms are detected (Intel's and Nvidia's), and each one sees its devices (intel has HD Graphics 4000 and Nvidia has my GPU: GeForce GT 630M).

My problem is that I am able to run my application using the Intel platform but not using Nvidia's platform. I don't believe the problem is in my code, but here is my device code:

```
#include "constants.h" //only a couple of #define

typedef struct Sphere {
    float x, y, z;
    float radius;
    float  r, g, b;
}Sphere;


float hit(Sphere s, float ox, float oy, float *n) {
    float radius = s.radius;
    float dx = ox - s.x;
    float dy = oy - s.y;
    if (dx*dx + dy*dy < radius*radius) {
        float dz = sqrt(radius*radius - dx*dx - dy*dy);
        *n = dz / sqrt(radius * radius);
        return dz + s.z;
    }
    return -INF;
}

__kernel void rayTracer(__global Sphere* spheres, write_only image2d_t res) {

    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    int ox = x - WIDTH / 2;
    int oy = y - HEIGHT / 2;

    float   r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    float   maxz = (float) -INF;

    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_SPHERES; i++) 
    {
        float   n;
        float   t = hit(spheres[i], ox, oy, &n);
        if (t > maxz) 
        { 
            float fscale = 1;
            r = spheres[i].r * fscale;
            g = spheres[i].g * fscale;
            b = spheres[i].b * fscale;
        }
    }
    write_imagei(res, (int2)(x, y), (int4)(r, g, b, 0));
}
```

My host application is also straightforward. I simply initialize openCL structures, setup the data and then read it back.

Again, when using the Intel platform my application runs fine and I can see the raytraced image. When using Nvidia's, although the API error codes are always 0, no result is displayed.

Does anybody have any Ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance

---EDIT---

Here are some pieces of host code

Setting up OpenCL structures:

```
//Setup OpenCL
cl_platform_id platform = getPlatforms();
cl_device_id device = getDevices(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);

cl_context_properties ctxProps[] =
{
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platform,
    0, 0
};
cl_context ctx = clCreateContext(ctxProps, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);
cl_command_queue queue1 = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, device, NULL, &err);
```

GetPlatforms and GetDevices are functions that asks the user to chose a platform and device

Creating the program and building it:

```
cl_program prog = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, srcs, &srcSize, &err);
err = clBuildProgram(prog, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (err < 0)
{
    //PRINT BUILD ERROR
    size_t log_size;
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(prog, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);
    char* log = (char*)calloc(log_size + 1, sizeof(char));
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(prog, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size + 1, log, NULL);
    printf("%s/n", log);
    free(log);
    std::cin >> err;
    return 1;
}
cl_kernel krn = clCreateKernel(prog, "rayTracer", &err);

//....CREATE SOME SPHERES...

//Setup device data
cl_image_format fmt;
fmt.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
fmt.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT8;

cl_mem spheresBuff = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, spheres.size() * sizeof(Sphere), spheres.data(), &err);
cl_mem resBuff = clCreateImage2D(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, &fmt, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, NULL, &err);

//Setup kernel arguments
err = clSetKernelArg(krn, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&spheresBuff);
err = clSetKernelArg(krn, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&resBuff);

//Run kernel
size_t gSize[] = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue1, krn, 2, NULL, gSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

//Read result
Image img = createRGBAImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

size_t origin[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
size_t region[] = { WIDTH , HEIGHT , 1 };
err = clEnqueueReadImage(queue1, resBuff, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, img.pixel.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: When you say 'no result is displayed', do you mean that the resulting image is blank? Can you show us some of the relevant host code (creation of the OpenCL buffers/images, kernel enqueue, host<->device transfers)?

Comment: Echoing what @jprice has said elsewhere: Are you checking status error return values in _every_ API call?

Comment: I've put some host code over there. While there is no error checking code in it, I've debugged the application and the error variable is always 0

Comment: And yes, i mean the the resulting image is blank

Comment: "While there is no error checking code in it, I've debugged the application and the error variable is always 0" is not sufficient debugging escpecially in kernel space. Speaking of which, why are you ray-tracing in kernel space? It seems like you are inviting problems for no gain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not a kernel problem. I have just changed the kernel to this single line and the resulting image is still blank:

write_imagei(res, (int2)(x, y), (int4)(255, 0, 255, 0));

Comment: Shouldn't the alpha value be 1, not 0? Also, you should use `write_imageui` instead of `write_imagei` since your image is a `CL_UNSIGNED_INT8`, although I'm not sure how much this will matter in practice.

Comment: Try writing your code without the int2 and int4 vectors. I ran into some trouble with AMD's implementation of the FFT on NVIDIA devices because they used float vectors. If it works on Intel / AMD / ATI, it is most likely a vector issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `clEnqueueMapBuffer` with CL_MAP_READ prior to kernel execution and `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` after kernel execution for your `spheresBuff`.